# How do I test a money object method

Tags: java, unit-testing, object, methods, junit

This is the method, it is part of a trip planning application:

```
public Money totalCost() {
    Money total = new Money();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < componentCount; ii++) {
        total.add(components[ii].getCost());     
    }
    return total;
}
```

I have to make a jUnit test for it, this is what I have so far:

```
public void testTotalCost() {
    Money testTotal = new Money();
    Money expected = testTotal;
    Money actual = tripTest1.totalCost();
    assertEquals("Error: ", expected, actual);  
}
```

I have to submit my program to an online website which says that I am not testing the following lines of the beginning method:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < componentCount; ii++) {
    total.add(components[ii].getCost());
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I suspect you've tested only one of the two following possibilities : `componentCount` is 0 or higher.

Comment: Yes, I've only test 0. I am not sure how to pass a value into the "actual" money object

Comment: I can't help on that, you haven't posted any code about Money object.

Comment: I do not have the money object code, all the money related code I have is posted above. Just to clarify I mean the "actual" as in expected and actual. So I know that to make expected a dollar amount, I can add two int values as a Money object parameter but how would I do that with the actual test variable?

Comment: The class that you are testing is the class of `tripTest1` and not the `Money` class. How does the `tripTest1`class look like. Have you already read a basic introduction to unit testing?